# Getting Error in visualforce page while preparing to display collection of account record names in picklistcontrol with the help of SelectOption

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

[image]

```java
  public class NewSectionOptions {

  public List<SelectOption> lstoptions {get; set;}
  // SelectOption is an apextype class to add elements to picklist control in vf page.
  public NewSectionOptions()
  {

    lstoptions = new List<SelectOption>();

    List<schema.Account> lstaccounts = [Select id, name from Account order by name];
//using sobject type class to collect list of records.....
    if(!lstaccounts.isEmpty())
    {
      for(Account acc : lstaccounts)
      {

        lstoptions.Add(new SelectOption(acc.id, acc.name));
        // Compile Error: Variable does not exist : id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you write your code? I copy/pasted it to my Dev Console and it was saved just fine, no errors

Comment: i wrote controller class in Visualforce  url page.....

Comment: try this [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) on how to build your custom controllers, maybe you write your code in a wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you have a custom class named Account, thus causing confusion with the compiler. Short of refactoring that class, you should add Schema to your for loop:

```
public class NewSectionOptions {

  public List<SelectOption> lstoptions {get; set;}
  // SelectOption is an apextype class to add elements to picklist control in vf page.
  public NewSectionOptions() {
    lstoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Schema.Account> lstaccounts = [Select id, name from Account order by name];
    //using sobject type class to collect list of records.....
    for(Schema.Account acc : lstaccounts) {
      lstoptions.Add(new SelectOption(acc.id, acc.name));
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that the if statement is not necessary, the code above should compile and run just fine.

Comment: Any way thanks for your time. I already  rectified and added schema in for loop .